# History of waiting for the Rav / Rabbi to finish Shemona Esrei

Tags: tefilla, rabbis, mishnah-berurah, tircha-detzibur, rama

[Rama - Orach Chaim 124:3](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=&pgnum=289) says that the one leading the prayers should not wait for the respected people to finish their Tefila. Mishna Berura 13 - says the reason is because of Tircha D'tzibura. Mishna Berura goes on and says that these days we do wait for האב״ד (this acronym is the Av Bais Din - perhaps extended to Rabbi or most Chashuv person in the Shul)

> ועכשיו נהגו שהש״ץ ממתין עד שיסיים האב״ד את תפלתו

My question is - What is the earliest recorded point after the Rama that this changed, and we started waiting for האב״ד / Rabbi prior to repeating the Tefila?

Comment: Wasn't that haLach written in the context of eating for someone who is praying longer than usual

Comment: Relatedly, I believe Rav Yaakov Kamenetsky, z"l, stopped praying at Beis Tefilla in Monsey when the congregation continued to wait for him even after he asked that they not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Mishna Brura is basically paraphrasing the Magein Avraham there (s.v. [אין לש"ץ להמתין](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x488)). This seems to be within the Magein Avraham's general approach of working to justify established customs that don't follow the Psak in Shulchan Aruch.

Note that the Rama's source is quoted as [Binyamin Zev #168](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=621&pgnum=533). In that Teshuva he is specifically responding to a custom to wait, so really the practice predates the Rama.

The [שו"ת ר"י מיגש #180](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1148&pgnum=60) speaks about someone in the congregation that has to be waited for before the one leading the prayers can start.

So it would appear the practice actually well predates the Rama into the times of the early Rishonim. However, in terms of justifying the practice after the Rama, we at least have the Magein Avraham (about a century later).